# How to add a style element inside a cell when the text inside changes to another value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a ReactJS app which shows from an API a table populated of flights information. One of the columns is called status and it is changing value when the status of flight changes.

For example, we have a flight in departures and the status now is "to gate" but later is "Boarding"
What I would like to achieve is to add a style element like for To gate a color or icon but when boarding a different color and so on. So I would like to change the cell based on what will be the status value.

I don't know how to do that as I'm new to React. I was thinking on the component below on the row/cell of status maybe it is possible to add an if which changes based on the value. Don't know if it possible.

My component looks like this:

```js
 class FlightComponent extends React.Component {
        render() {
            const { data, activeTab } = this.props;
            let columns = [
                //{ Header: 'Date', accessor: 'date' },
                { Header: 'Time', accessor: 'time' },
                { Header: 'Expected', accessor: 'expected', Cell: (row) => (<div className="expected">{row.value}</div>) },
                { Header: 'Airline', accessor: 'airline', Cell: (row) => (<div className="airline-name">{row.value}</div>) },
                { Header: 'Flight No.', accessor: 'flight_no'},
            ];
            if (activeTab == 1) {
                columns.push({ Header: 'Destination', accessor: 'destination' })
            } else {
                columns.push({ Header: 'Arriving From', accessor: 'arriving_from' })
            }
            columns = columns.concat([
                { Header: 'Gate', accessor: 'gate' },
                { Header: 'Terminal', accessor: 'terminal' },
                { Header: 'Status', accessor: 'status' }
            ]);

            return (
                <div>
                    <ReactTable
                        columns={ columns }
                        data = {this.props.data}
                    />
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: You just need to make `className` conditional, something like `className={boarding ? 'blue' : 'red'}`. This is just an example of any condicional className, not something that will work for you.

Comment: Could show me an example using the status vakues I have:
to gate, boarding, closing and closed? Will help me to understand better

Comment: I tried this  { Header: 'Status', accessor: 'status', Cell: (row) => (<div className={'To gate' ? 'red' : 'green'}>{row.value}</div>) } but I need that when vakues is to gate shows something when boarding something else closing and closed the same that I cannot achieve

Comment: The condition is wrong, you need to make a comparison like `status === 'To gate' ? 'red' : 'green'`, you can't just have `To gate` there, because that will always be treated as `true` (for Javascript, strings that aren't empty are "truthy", which means that even though they aren't exactly `true`, they are "converted" to true when used in conditions like that). Think of it as an `if` statement, where the stuff before the `?` is a condition, the stuff after the `?` is what you want to happen if the condition is true, and the stuff after the `:` is what happens if the condition is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [react-table](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme) you could use `Custom Cell, Header and Footer Rendering`

You can use any react component or JSX to display content in column headers, cells and footers. Any component you use will be passed the following props (if available):

- **row** - Original row from your data
  original - The post-accessed values from the original row
- **index** - The index of the row
- **viewIndex** - the index of the row relative to the current page
- **level** - The nesting depth (zero-indexed)
- **nestingPath** - The nesting path of the row
- **aggregated** - A boolean stating if the row is an aggregation row
- **subRows** - An array of any expandable sub-rows contained in this row

You can check, here is wokring **[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-add-a-style-element-inside-a-cell-when-the-text-inside-c)** demo.

---

**Code Snippet**

```js
render() {
    const data = [{
        task: 'Demo 1',
        status: 'pending'
    }, {
        task: 'Demo 2',
        status: 'completed'
    }]

    const columns = [{
        Header: 'Task Name',
        accessor: 'task'
    }, {
        Header: 'Status',
        accessor: 'status',
        Cell: (row, original, index, viewIndex, level, nestingPath, aggregated, subRows) => {
            row.styles['color'] = '#fff';
            row.styles['backgroundColor'] = row.value == 'pending' ? 'red' : 'green';
            return row.value.toUpperCase();
        }
    }];

    return (
       <ReactTable
        data={data}
        columns={columns}
        defaultPageSize={5}
        className="-striped -highlight"
      />
    );

}
```